# Attachments in kanban view Odoo 8

Tags: binary, attachment, odoo-8, kanban

I need to show attachments in kanban view.

```
<record id="view_document_ir_attachment_kanban" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">ir.attachment.kanban</field>
        <field name="model">ir.attachment</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <kanban create="false">
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="datas" />
                <templates>
                    <t t-name="kanban-box">
                        <div style="width: 100px;">
                            <field name="name" />
                            <field name="data"/>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </templates>
            </kanban>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Here field data is the binary field.

Comment: If you check the Documents menu under Knowledge, you can see the Documents in kanban view also.

Comment: you meant Settings->Configurations->knowledge->Manage documents, i already check this, but change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\addons\document\document_view.xml  after line 256. add this

```
<menuitem name="Documents" id="menu_document_doc" parent="knowledge.menu_document" sequence="0"/>

<menuitem name="Documents" action="action_document_file_form" id="menu_document_files" parent="menu_document_doc" sequence="0"/>
```